Linear transformation $X\mapsto A^tX A-X$ on $M_n(F)$
Let $F$ be a finite field, $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ with char $F\neq 2$.
Let $M_n(F)$ be the set of $n\times n$ matrices over $F$.
The problem is that if $A\in M_n (F)$, the linear transformation
$$f:M_n(F)\to M_n(F),\qquad X\mapsto A^tXA-X$$
is invertible if and only if no two characteristic roots of $A$ are inverses.
I think the statement means the roots of $|\lambda I-A|$ in its splitting field.
I try to write down my way, which is too complicated. I wonder there is a better way.

Let $E$ be the splitting field of $|\lambda I-A|$.
If $\lambda I-A$ has eigenvalue $\mu$ and $1/\mu$, with $x,y\in E^n$ satisfying
$$Ax=\mu x,\quad Ay=\frac{1}{\mu}y.$$
With $Y=x\cdot y^t\in M_n(E)$, we have $f(Y)=0$.
Note that norm is surjective form $E^*$ to $F^*$.
By considering $Y'=cY$ for suitable $c\in E$, , we can have
$$0\neq Z=Norm(Y')=\sum_{g\in Gal(E/F)}g(Y')\in M_n (F).$$
And we have $f(Z)=0$.
Now assume $A$ is not invertible. Note that
$$X=\frac{1}{2}(X+X^t)+\frac{1}{2}(X-X^t),$$
we have $M_n(F)=U\oplus V$, where $U$ consists of symmetric matrices and $V$ consists of skew symmetric matrices. Note that $U$ and $V$ are $f$ invariant subspaces. So we must have some non-zero $X$ satisfying $f(X)=0$ with $X\in V$ or $W$.
We first consider the symmetric case.
Now we have a quadratic form on $W=E^n$, with $(x,y)=x^tXy$ and $g:x\mapsto Ax$ is a orthogonal transformation of $W$.
Consider the quotient space $W_1=W/rad(W)$, where
$$rad(W)=\{\text{$z:(z,x)=0$ for all $x\in W$}\}.$$
Then the quadratic form on $W_1$ is non-degenerate,
where $\hat{x}=x+rad(W)$ and $(\hat{x},\hat{y})=x^t Xy$.
The linear transfomation $\hat{A}:\hat{x}\to \widehat{Ax}$ is orthogonal, where $rad(W)$ is $A$ invariant subspace.
Assume $\hat{A}\hat{x}=\mu \hat{x}$.
If $(\hat{x},\hat{x})=0$, by considering a hyperbolic pair $\hat{y}$ with $(\hat{x},\hat{y})=1$ and $(\hat{y},\hat{y})=0$.
$$\hat{A}\hat{y}=c\hat{x}+\frac{1}{\mu}\hat{y}+\hat{u},\qquad \hat{u}\in(E\hat{x}+E\hat{y})^\perp.$$
Consider a basis $\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{u_i}$ with $\hat{u_i}\in(E\hat{x}+E\hat{y})^\perp$.
Note that $\hat{A}(E\hat{x})^\perp\subset (E\hat{x})^\perp$, that is
$\hat{A}(\hat{u_i})\in\langle \hat{x},\hat{u_1},\ldots,\hat{u_s}\rangle$.
Se see that $\frac{1}{\mu}$ is an eigenvalue of $\hat{A}$, hence of $A$.
If $(\hat{x},\hat{x})\neq 0$, then we reduce the action of $\hat{A}$ to its orthogonal complement. And In two dimensional case, by choosing a suitable base, we have
$$X=I,-I,\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
The skew symmetric case is easier. Assume $\hat{A}\hat{x}=\mu \hat{x}$. We can always find a $\hat{y}$ with $(\hat{x},\hat{y})=1$. Then
$$\hat{A}\hat{y}=c\hat{x}+\frac{1}{\mu}\hat{y}+\hat{u},\qquad \hat{u}\in(E\hat{x}+E\hat{y})^\perp.$$

@JyrkiLahtonen No matter which A you choose, $f(0) = A0A^t - 0 = 0$. What fails is rather that $f(X) = 0$ is possible for some $X\neq 0$. I do believe a typo happened between the title of the question and its content

If you fix your formula yes it is in the splitting field, since rank does not depend on field extension. Also you could change this property by saying no irreducible polynomial in the decomposition of the characteristic polynomial is preserved by mirror reflexion

I corrected it since your title had no flaw

If you are looking for a shorter approach, this comes down to looking at fixed points of $T: M_n(\mathbb F)\longrightarrow M_n(\mathbb F)$ given by $T(X) =A^T X A$.  I suggest using Kronecker Products.   I don't think any of the field restrictions in the first sentence are needed.

The first part of your proof, establishing that $f$ fails to be invertible if and only if $A$ has two eigenvalues (in some field extension) that are inverses, is fine.
It can be made faster if we use the fact that for a vector space $V$ over $F$, an $F$-linear map $\phi: V \to V$ is invertible if and only if its associated $E$-linear map $\tilde \phi :V^E \to V^E$ (where $V^E$ can be constructed by extension of scalars) is also invertible. Rather than considering the kernel as you have done, you can simply note that the determinants $\det(\phi), \det(\tilde \phi)$ are equal. For you proof, take $\phi = f - \text{id}$.
A quick approach to the entire proof, however, is to use established facts about the Kronecker product. In particular:

Relative to a certain "standard" basis of $F^n$, the matrix of $f$ is given by
$$
A^t \otimes A^t
$$
For matrices $P,Q$ of sizes $m \times m, n \times n$, the eigenvalues of a Kronecker product $P \otimes Q$ are given by the products of the form $\lambda_j \mu_k$, where $\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_m$ are the eigenvalues of $P$ and $\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n$ the eigenvalues of $Q$.

Thus, $f$ is invertible if and only if its matrix $A^t \otimes A^t$ is invertible, which is true if and only if $A^t$ (and hence $A$) has eigenvalues $\lambda_i,\lambda_j$ (within a suitable extension) such that $\lambda_i\lambda_j = 1$.

Very clean approach
